# openstreetmap data statistics page for the current planet dataset

Tags: openstreetmap

Is there a page where one can se statistics about the current planet dataset, for example: what is the number of points in the largest geometry (or maybe a distribution of the number of points)?

Any statistics page would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stats) are various statistics, especially the [database statistics](http://www.openstreetmap.org/stats/data_stats.html) and [taginfo](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/) might be of interest for you. Also don't miss the list of [external statistics](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stats#External_sites_with_active_statistics_and_reports).